# How to remove double quotes from file but not inside the double quotes

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, perl

We have example of partial CSV file ( with only 3 fields )

our target is to remove all `"` characters but not inside the double quotes

```
ssl-server,"ssl.server.truststore.type","jks"
tez-env,"enable_heap_"\n"dump","false"
tez-env,"heap_dump_location"\n"port","/tmp"
tez-env,"tez_user","tez"
```

expected output:

```
ssl-server,ssl.server.truststore.type,jks
tez-env,enable_heap_"\n"dump,false
tez-env,heap_dump_location"\n"port,/tmp
tez-env,tez_user,tez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use dedicated software for csv manipulation, although this case could be solved with simple `sed` if there are no commas inside double quotes:

```
sed 's/^"//;s/",/,/g;s/,"/,/g;s/"$//' file
```

Comment: The CVSKit toolkit doesn't properly grok this data since it's improperly quoted from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***sed*** solution:

```
sed 's/^"\|"$//g; s/"*,"*/,/g;' file
```

---

Or ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i) }1' OFS=',' file
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
ssl-server,ssl.server.truststore.type,jks
tez-env,enable_heap_"\n"dump,false
tez-env,heap_dump_location"\n"port,/tmp
tez-env,tez_user,tez
```